# Did Dempsey and Makepeace have some intimacy together?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, dempsey-and-makepeace

In good old [Dempsey and Makepeace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempsey_and_Makepeace) , there was excellent tension between them during the whole series. Dempsey wanted to win her over, but Makepeace was cooling him down all the time ;-). Did they finally managed to have some intimacy together? Or did they even sleep together?

Comment: There is no need to add smiles and "good and old", they are not adding any value to the question.

Comment: Ankit yes they have emotional value. This page is about movies, this is not Stackoverflow. I find these your edits of no use, if not even offensive.

Comment: Whether or not this is SO, this is still part of the Stack Exchange network of sites. While some embellishment is alright, smilies and the like just bloat the question and add no value to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempsey_and_Makepeace) cited in the question says,

> Much of the show's draw came from the good natured "will they or won't they" interplay and a suspected slowly evolving romance between the main protagonists, made possible by the obvious chemistry between the two lead actors. The show ended with an episode directed by Michael Brandon himself where Dempsey and Makepeace are forced to confront at least some of their feelings for one another.

That sounds like the answer is no; but to make it explicit, we have the following from an
[IMDb user review](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088503/reviews-1):

> My only complaint is that they never got together romatically and I think that they should have.

However, there is a kicker to this story (described nicely on this [fan page](http://strony.aster.pl/dempsey/actors.htm)):  As
mentioned, there was "chemistry" between the
lead actors, Michael Brandon (Dempsey) and Glynis Barber (Makepeace).  A year after the
show ended, having been separated by work at various locations, they decided to renew
their partnership and make it permanent in real life.  They married on 19 November 1989,
and are still together after more than twenty-three years.